# How to use try, throw and catch?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, throw

I'm trying to use `try, throw and catch` in a piece of code to test if an input is good. This is what I have so far;

```
 while(loop > 0){
    try{
        cout << "Please input the x and y centre point: separated by a space" << endl;
        cin >> Cx >> Cy;
        if(isalpha(Cx)){cin.clear(); cin.ignore();throw 1;}
        if(isalpha(Cy)){cin.clear(); cin.ignore();throw 2;}

        cout << "Please input the side length" << endl;
        cin >> side1;
        if(isalpha(side1)){cin.clear(); cin.ignore();throw 3;}
        if(side1 <= 0){cin.clear(); cin.ignore();throw 4;}

        loop = 0;
    }
    catch(int err){
        if(err == 1){cout << "X center co-ordinate should be a number" << endl;}
        if(err == 2){cout << "Y center co-ordinate should be a number" << endl;}
        if(err == 3){cout << "The length should be a number" << endl;}
        if(err == 4){cout << "The length should be greater than 0" << endl;}
    }
}
```

When I run this, and enter `o 0` for the centre point the program still outputs `Please input the side length` and then `The length should be greater than 0` and finally loops back to ask for a new centre point.

How should I change this so that the correct error message is read out before the side length line (ideally the side length line wouldn't be outputted)?

Thanks

I am new to using `try, throw and catch` and from what I've read this might not be the right application of it but I just want to try it out.

Comment: what programing language are you using?

Comment: Can you write a question title that better reflects what you are asking?

Comment: There's a reason why they're called exceptions. If you need to handle type(s) of exceptions that are out of your control / expectation, then you would use a try/catch. This does not apply to validating user input, because you can expect what they will enter, valid or otherwise. Just write a validation routine with returning error message/code.

Comment: Whether one should use exceptions to handle user input errors is wildly and widely debated. To me, a user making a mistake while typing input is not exceptional. It is instead exceptionally common.

Comment: @DarylYoung - you're correct, but the OP wants to understand usage, not application (and says so in the last line of his question).  It seems his implementation is correct,

Comment: IMO you shouldn't use the exception mechanism to control the *normal* flow of the program. Use it for *exceptional* things that you do not normally expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide running code or any debug information we're forced to guess (and write the program ourselves).  See below, which works perfectly under cygwin 4.9.2 / Windows 7.  Modify your program to match or post the full non-correct code for another attempt.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int loop = 1;
    char Cx, Cy;
    char side1;
    while(loop){
        try{
            cout << "Please input the x and y centre point: separated by a space" << endl;
            cin >> Cx >> Cy;

            if(isalpha(Cx)){cin.clear(); cin.ignore();throw 1;}
            if(isalpha(Cy)){cin.clear(); cin.ignore();throw 2;}

            cout << "Please input the side length" << endl;
            cin >> side1;
            if(isalpha(side1)){cin.clear(); cin.ignore();throw 3;}
            if(side1 <= 0){cin.clear(); cin.ignore();throw 4;}

            loop = 0;
        }
        catch(int err){
            if(err == 1){cout << "X center co-ordinate should be a number" << endl;}
            if(err == 2){cout << "Y center co-ordinate should be a number" << endl;}
            if(err == 3){cout << "The length should be a number" << endl;}
            if(err == 4){cout << "The length should be greater than 0" << endl;}
        }
    }
}
```